# Excel - combining two csv files into one with a common column

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I am working with two datasets in `csv` form (movielens latest-small dataset). Given below are the fields of both.

rating.csv

```
  user_id   movie_id  rating
```

movie.csv

```
  movie_id   movie_name
```

what I want is to combine them into a single .csv with following fields

```
user_id   movie_id   movie_name   rating
```

So that the common column `movie_id` maps with corresponding `movie_name`.

Could that be done using Excel? If not, how can I do it?

I just need it as a dataset for my *recommender* engine, so any simple solution is welcome as end result is all that matters. But since I've some experience in java so that would be easy for my easy understand and implement.

If there is some way using Excel then that would be the best. I have tried searching online and found some `VLOOKUP` method but couldn't clearly get it.

Also I tried some online merging tools but they just attached the sheets one after the another not mapping the column. So I have no problem using online tools too.

Comment: As is stands your questions is a little bit 'too broad' - can you please update your question to indicate *how* you are trying to do this merge e.g. within Excel with formulas; with VBA; with some other language/ framework ?

Comment: So will your recommender engine be written in Java? If you were to use .Net, you could use LINQ to run a query that combines them both and use that dataset in memory. I'm not sure of the equivalent in Java though.

Comment: Yes, it is in java. But what wonders me is that can't it be done using excel or online tool.I thought it to be a routine operation that doesn't require any script . Can combining two csv  be so complex?

Comment: @techvigil - use the VLOOKUP formula and then save as a csv in one shot - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this tool - https://github.com/DataFoxCo/gocsv - it's based off of csvkit but has a ton of additional features. One of our engineers custom built it - and open sourced it to help solve some of these data issues we deal with every day :)

It will do a vlookup essentially of any sized csv in merely seconds using the join command:

`gocsv join --columns 'movie_id','movie_id' --left rating.csv movie.csv  > combineddata.csv`

then if you still want to reorder the columns, you can do that too:

`gocsv select --columns 'user_id','movie_id','movie_name','rating' combineddata.csv > combineddata-final.csv`

I split the commands out up top to help explain its use - the documentation has all the examples on it also but ultimately I would really recommend pipelining it and doing it in one command like this:

`cat rating.csv \
  | gocsv join --left --columns 'movie_id','movie_id' movie.csv \
  | gocsv select --columns 'user_id','movie_id','movie_name','rating' > combineddata.csv`

Answer (score 1):

This is the method with a `VLOOKUP` formula within Excel:

[image]

The formula takes 4 arguments:

1. The value you are wanting to look up
2. The range of data you are looking into
3. The column within (2) that contains the answer you want
4. Whether to match on (1) approximately i.e. FALSE = exact match

See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) for documentation on the function.